# Android reboot command - Who calls reboot_main()?

Tags: android, c, linker, embedded-linux, static-linking

I am looking at the source for the android shell **[reboot](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/toolbox/reboot.c)** command.

```
int reboot_main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

- What I am not clear about is if this is a standalone binary, who calls reboot_main() ?
- In a standard glibc linked binary, I was expecting to find a "main()" as the entry point for the program.

What am I missing here, could someone help me understand what is going on ?

Thanks,
vj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are all compiled into one overall executable, with `main` in https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core.git/+/android-4.2.2_r1/toolbox/toolbox.c

Then, based on the actual program name invoked (usually `argv[0]`) it calls the appropriate method.

The commands are part of the build via the

```
#define TOOL(name) int name##_main(int, char**);
```

macro in `toolbox.c` which is used in the `Android.mk` file to generate `tools.h`.